# How to hide Status(standard field) values when status has particular value

Tags: validation, validation-rule, action, status

Can anyone suggest me to achieve below action.

I am using Status Field, when ever the status value is Open then i should be allowed only to few status like "In Progress" and "Need Information". And when ever the status is in In Progress it should allow me only to Move to Open or Resolved. If status is in Resolved then it should allow only to Closed.

Open --> In PRogress
     ---> Need Information

In PRogress --> Open
            --> Resolved

Resolved --> Closed

Can anyone help me please.

Thanks & Regards,
Srinivas

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by configuration. Create one record type for each possible phase, and restrict picklist values based on the record type. You can then use workflow rules to change record types when the status changes.